# Getting an Error in my event log of Team Foundation Server

Tags: c#, tfs, w3wp.exe

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this, but I'm getting an error in my eventlog every time I open my TFS webpage I get the following error:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="Microsoft-Team Foundation Server" Guid="{80761876-6844-47D5-8106-F8ED2AA8687B}" /> 
<EventID>0</EventID> 
<Version>0</Version> 
<Level>2</Level> 
<Task>1</Task> 
<Opcode>10</Opcode> 
<Keywords>0x8000000000000001</Keywords> 
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-02-24T14:48:40.361409100Z" /> 
<EventRecordID>650</EventRecordID> 
<Correlation ActivityID="{72451AFD-6F04-0000-3340-4572046FD101}" /> 
<Execution ProcessID="3932" ThreadID="808" /> 
<Channel>Microsoft-Team Foundation Server/Debug</Channel> 
<Computer>WIN-U8K4FA701IJ</Computer> 
<Security UserID="S-1-5-19" /> 
</System>
<UserData>
<Info TraceId="{00000001-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2010/Framework">
 <Tracepoint>599999</Tracepoint> 
 <ServiceHost>{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</ServiceHost> 
 <ContextId>0</ContextId> 
 <ProcessName>w3wp</ProcessName> 
 <Username /> 
 <Service /> 
 <Method /> 
 <Area>WebAccess</Area> 
 <Layer>Controller</Layer> 
 <UserAgent /> 
 <Uri /> 
 <Path /> 
 <UserDefined /> 
 <Message>System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Kan een of meer van de gevraagde typen niet laden. Haal de LoaderExceptions-eigenschap op voor meer informatie. bij System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module) bij System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes() bij System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() bij Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.TypeUtils.GetAllTypes(IEnumerable`1 assemblies, Func`2 filter)</Message> 
</Info>
</UserData>
</Event>
```

I tried re-installing everything but it didn't bother.
Who knows what is giving me this error?

Comment: What version of TFS? What OS?

Comment: Tfs2012 and Windows server 2012

Comment: Is your TFS working as expected?

Comment: Has your TFS 2012 been upgraded to the latest edition Update4?

Comment: I updated to update 4 but that is only for Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

First, translate the error message into English to make it readable:

```
<Message>System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.TypeUtils.GetAllTypes(IEnumerable`1 assemblies, Func`2 filter)</Message>
```

This error may be caused by various factors, for example, if you don't configure build service well. Try to install the [TFS 2012 Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f), then run the BPA to scan your TFS 2012 Server, you may get something useful.

Comment: I didn't get anything useful from BPA for this occasion

Comment: it is, but when I build a plugin it crashes

Comment: Though my TFS server is working fine, getting an error log like this and now stuck at how to recognize the issue. Did you resolve this?